# Bootstrap datetimepicker form overlaps when web page is scrolled up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have created two datatimepicker element on my page using the following code:

```
  <h3>Start Date Time</h3>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date form_datetime_start">
      <input class="form-control" readonly disabled>
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
      </span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Using the following files as well:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

And the jquery code :

```
$('.form_datetime_start').datetimepicker({
    format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    clearBtn: true,
    startDate: "2017-07-23 10:00",
    minuteStep: 5
});
```

It works fine with the only problem that the form overlaps when the web page is scrolled up. The first image is the unscrolled page and the second the scrolled one

[image: Unscrolled]
[image: Scrolled]

What can I do in order to fix this kind of problem?

Comment: Can you share a working snippet showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like the the  field has a higher stack order than the fixed header. You can try setting a higher z-index property for the fixed header e.g.

```
.header{ //define your class for the fixed header
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't help. What I also see was that this overlap goes away when I remove the input-group class from div but without it the datetimepicker does not work properly.